# Discretization of a diff. equation gives weird results

Tags: python, scipy

I have a code in Python that draws wave functions and energy for different potentials:

```
    # -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
from math import *
from scipy.special import *
from pylab import *
from scipy.linalg import *

firebrick=(178./255.,34./255.,34./255.)
indianred=(176./255.,23./255.,31./255.)
steelblue=(70./255.,130./255.,180./255.)
slategray1=(198./255.,226./255.,255./255.)
slategray4=(108./255.,123./255.,139./255.)
lavender=(230./255.,230./255.,230./255.)
cobalt=(61./255.,89./255.,171./255.)
midnightblue=(25./255.,25./255.,112./255.)
forestgreen=(34./255.,139./255.,34./255.)

#definiranje mreze
Nmesh=512
L=4.0
dx=L/Nmesh
Xmax=L
x=arange(-L,L+0.0001,dx)
Npts=len(x)
numwav=0 #redni broj valne funkcije koji se iscrtava

V=zeros([Npts],float)
for i in range(Npts):
    V[i]=x[i]**50

a=zeros([2,Npts-2],float)
wave=zeros([Npts],float)

wave1=zeros([Npts],float)
encor=3.0/4*(3.0/4)**(1.0/3)

#numericko rjesenje
for i in range(1,Npts-1,1):
    a[0,i-1]= 1.0/dx**2+V[i]     #dijagonalni elementi
    a[1,i-1]=-1.0/dx**2/2        #elementi ispod dijagonale
a[1,Npts-3]=-99.0                #element se ne koristi
eig,vec=eig_banded(a,lower=1)    #rutina koja dijagonalizira tridijagonalnu matricu

for i in range(1,Npts-1,1):
    wave[i]=vec[i-1,numwav]
wave[0]=0.0             #valna funkcija u prvoj tocki na mrezi ima vrijednost nula
wave[Npts-1]=0.0        #valna funkcija u zadnjoj tocki na mrezi ima vrijednost nula

for i in range(1,Npts-1,1):
    wave1[i]=(2.0/pi*(3.0/4)**(1.0/3))**0.25*exp(-(3.0/4)**(1.0/3)*x[i]**2)
wave1[0]=0.0             #valna funkcija u prvoj tocki na mrezi ima vrijednost nula
#wave1[Npts-1]=0.0        #valna funkcija u zadnjoj tocki na mrezi ima vrijednost nula


#wave1=omjer*150*wave1+encor
wave=150*wave+eig[numwav]

#graf potencijala
line=plt.plot(x,V)
plt.setp(line,color='firebrick',linewidth=2)

#crtanje odabranog nivoa i odgovarajuce valne funkcije
plt.axhline(y=eig[numwav],linewidth=2,color='steelblue')
#plt.axhline(y=encor,linewidth=2,color='midnightblue')


#crtanje tocaka valne funkcije
plt.plot(x,wave,"b-",linewidth=2,color='forestgreen')
#plt.plot(x,wave1,"-",linewidth=2,color='indianred')

plt.xlabel(r'$x$',size=14)
plt.ylabel(r'$V(x)$',size=14)
plt.title(r'Valna funkcija i energija 3. pobuđenog stanja za $V(x)=x^{50}$')
plt.axis([-3.0,3.0,-8.0,100.0]) #raspon x i y osi
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend((r'$V(x)$',r'$E_0$',r'$\psi_0$'))
plt.show()
```

Ignore the ignored lines, they are not important for this case, and the language :D

Anyhow, I have a problem. If I draw the potentials (the `V` part), for let's say up to `x^20` it draws nice, like this for `x^6`:

[image: potential1]

If I put the potential, say `x^50` it becomes this:

[image: potential2]

So what seems to be the problem? Why is he making such big mistake? It should be smooth, and from the theory as I reach the point `V(x)=x^p` for very large `p` (p → ∞) the potential should go to the famous infinite square well, which looks like this:

[image: potential3]

So I'm suspecting that for bigger potentials I need more points to draw it in the given range. So should I just increase the number of the `Nmesh` (grid)? Since he says that the `Npts=len(x)` - the number of points he's taking. Am I right? That seems logical, but I want to be certain.

Thanks for any advice and help

EDIT: I tried expanding the `Nmesh` but at very large numbers I either get that grid is too big, or that there is memory problems.

If I take, say 2048 I get the same picture but just shifted a bit and narrower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select` argument for [`eig_banded()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig_banded.html#scipy.linalg.eig_banded):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
import functools
import math
import sys

from timeit import default_timer as timer

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.linalg as linalg

def report_time(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = timer()
        try: return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            print '%s takes %.2f seconds' % (func.__name__, timer()-start)
    return wrapper

@report_time
def calc(Nmesh,POWER,L ,numwav=0):
    #
    dx=L/Nmesh
    x = np.arange(-L,L+0.0001,dx)
    Npts=len(x)

    V = x**POWER

    #
    ai = np.empty((2,Npts))   # ai[:,i] = a[:,i-1]
    ai[0,:] = 1/dx**2 + V     #
    ai[1,:] = -1.0/dx**2/2    #
    ai[1,Npts-2] = -99.0      #
    a = ai[:,1:-1]
    f = report_time(linalg.eig_banded)
    eig, vec = f(a, lower=True,overwrite_a_band=True,
                 select='i',select_range=(0,numwav)
                 ) #

    wave = np.empty(Npts)
    wave[1:-1] = vec[:,numwav]
    wave[0] = 0             #
    wave[Npts-1] = 0        #
    wave = 150*wave + eig[numwav]
    return x, V, wave, eig[numwav]

def main():
    try: numwav = int(sys.argv[1])
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        numwav = 0
    POWER=100
    L=4.0
    Nmesh = 512
    print 'Nmesh=%d' % Nmesh
    x, V, wave, y = calc(Nmesh, POWER, L,numwav)

    #
    line = plt.plot(x,V)
    plt.setp(line,color='firebrick',linewidth=2)

    #
    plt.plot(x,wave,"b-",linewidth=2,color='forestgreen')

    #
    plt.axhline(y=y,linewidth=2,color='steelblue')

    plt.xlabel(r'$x$',size=14)
    plt.ylabel(r'$V(x)$',size=14)
    plt.title(r'$V(x)=x^{%d}$, ' % POWER)
    plt.axis([-(abs(L)-1), abs(L)-1,min(min(wave), y, min(V))-1, max(max(wave), y)+1]) #
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend((r'$V(x)$',r'$E_%d$' % numwav,r'$\psi_%d$' % numwav))
    plt.savefig('V_%d_%d_%d.png' % (Nmesh, POWER, numwav))
    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

#### Output

```
Nmesh=512
eig_banded takes 0.01 seconds
calc takes 0.01 seconds
```

[image: V(x)=x**100]

Here's a variant with `numwav=4`:

[image: numwav]

Comment: OMNG!

This looks just... I have no words...

So what did you change (except that you made the code much nicer, compact)? I still don't really understand why my code wouldn't process higher powers, but played nicely with lower ones :\

I cannot tell you how grateful I am :) 

Oh and btw, you have really fast computer :D 

`Nmesh=512
eig_banded takes 0.08 seconds
calc takes 0.12 seconds`

Comment: **EDIT:**
I have ran into a small problem, I keep looking at the code to see what's wrong, but to no avail. If I want to see different numwav (1, 2, 3...) I get error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File [...], line 53, in <module>
    x, V, wave, y = calc(Nmesh, POWER, L)
  File [...], line 16, in wrapper
    try: return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File [...], line 43, in calc
    wave[1:-1] = vec[:,numwav]
IndexError: invalid index`
Why doesn't it want to plot the higher states? I'm sorry if I'm bothering you :(

Comment: Ok I found it! Selected range of the eig.banded wasn't good. I put:
`select_range=(numwav-numwav,numwav)` and now it draws perfectly ^^

Thanks again very very very much ^^ :D

Comment: I have a question: is there any way I can incorporate the numwav so that it automatically makes the labels according to it, and pictures according to it?

E.g. I put numwav=1.0 and the labels will automatically out psi_1, E_1 etc. ?

Comment: @dingo_d: Do you mean `plt.legend((r'$V(x)$',r'$E_%d$' % numwav,r'$\psi_%d$' % numwav))` or something else? You could ask it as a separate question, thus more people could see it and would be able to answer.

Comment: Something like that, I tried it but it doesn't plot it and returns this:
`plt.legend((r'$V(x)$',r'$E_%d$' % numwav,r'$\psi_%d$' % numwav))
NameError: name 'numwav' is not defined`

Comment: @dingo_d: I've added a variant with `numwav=4`. Passing a variable as a parameter to a function is a rather basic stuff. Try to work through some beginner tutorials such as http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index to avoid being stuck on trivial errors

Comment: I'll look at the tutorials, thank you again very much, you've saved me XD