# Getting 4 rather than 4.76 as answer to math / science problem (always integer not decimal)

Tags: python, math

So this is in a way connected to my problem with drawing the energy levels etc. [link to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528803/discretization-of-a-diff-equation-gives-weird-results).

Anywho, I was using discretization to get the energy levels and wave functions for various potentials, and I'm probably a tool in programming, because I have no idea how to get the numerical result for the energy eigenvalues. I have a strong sense that it has to be possible to just extract that information from the given code (the code has eig_banded routine from linalg module). But I'm just a tool and cannot figure how to do it :\

So I just need the numerical value of the energy that I draw...

I tried with (this is a part of the code from the link):

```
    def calc(Nmesh,POWER,L ,numwav=0):
    #
    dx=L/Nmesh
    x = np.arange(-L,L+0.0001,dx)
    Npts=len(x)

    V = x**POWER

    #
    ai = np.empty((2,Npts))   # ai[:,i] = a[:,i-1]
    ai[0,:] = 1/dx**2 + V     #
    ai[1,:] = -1.0/dx**2/2    #
    ai[1,Npts-2] = -99.0      #
    a = ai[:,1:-1]
    f = report_time(linalg.eig_banded)
    eig, vec = f(a, lower=True,overwrite_a_band=True,
                 select='i',select_range=(0,numwav)
                 ) #

    wave = np.empty(Npts)
    wave[1:-1] = vec[:,numwav]
    wave[0] = 0             #
    wave[Npts-1] = 0        #
    wave = 150*wave + eig[numwav]
    return x, V, wave, eig[numwav]

def main():
    try: numwav = int(sys.argv[1])
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        numwav = 2
    POWER=4
    L=4.0
    Nmesh = 512
    print 'Nmesh=%d' % Nmesh
    x, V, wave, y = calc(Nmesh, POWER, L,numwav)
    print 'Energy eigenvalue is: %d' % y
```

But for this instance it will give that eigenvalue is 4, and on the plot it's closer to the 4.76...

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
>>> '%d' % 1.2
'1'
```

The format string you want is %f to show decimal

```
>>> '%f' % 1.2
'1.200000'
```

The clutch of the diagnosis was the fact that it was an integer rather than a float you were seeing.

More information can be found at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html
For example, you can use the following format to round:

```
>>> '%.2f' % 1.234
'1.23'
>>> '%.2f' % 1.236
'1.24'
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the problem :D Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

Is this your problem?

```
>>> 1/2
0
```

If so, this is your solution:

```
>>> from __future__ import division

>>> 1/2
0.5
```

Comment: Or ``1.0/2`` (implicit promotion to float) or ``float(1)/2`` if you don't want to use the ``__future__`` import.

Comment: Nope I have the division imported :\ I just need to get the eigenvalue of this problem. It must be there because it draws the said eigenvalue... I just need it to give me the numerical value of it (it draws the straight line with constant y, and I need to find out that y).

Here is a picture of the problem: [link](http://i.imgur.com/vV1fb.jpg)